# AngularJS Testing with Jasmine and Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

i try to test an angular controller but he returns a promise and i cant really resolve it...what's wrong with my code?

the Angular Controller:

```
kpi.AboutController = function ($scope, Version) {

    function loadVersion() {
        //$scope.version = Version.getVersion();
        $scope.version = '1.1.0';
    }

    loadVersion();
};
```

and the jasmine test:

```
describe('dashboard: AboutController', function() {
beforeEach(module('dashboard'));
var $controller;
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
}));
it('testing the version number', function() {
    var $scope = {};
    var controller = $controller('AboutController', { $scope: $scope });
    var version = 0;
    console.log($scope.version);
    expect($scope.version).toContain("1.");
});
});
```

this is working, but when i change the line `$scope.version = '1.1.0';` to `$scope.version = Version.getVersion();` i receive a promise and i can not rly check it....i tried to resolve it with "then()" function via `$scope.version.then(...)`but that did not work...what to do?

edit:

the following error occures:

```
Expected e({ $promise: Object({ $$state: Object({ status: 0 }) }), $resolved: false }) to contain '1.'.
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

and the Service:

```
kpi.VersionFactory = function ($resource, appConfig) {
var Version = $resource(thePath, {}, {

    "getVersion": {
        method: "GET",
        url: thePath,
        isArray: false
    }

});

return Version;
};
```

Comment: can you show the error ?

Comment: What's the code of the `Version` being injected in the controller ? This cannot be answered without it.

Comment: Please show the angular service `Version`. What you showed is ...Java?

Comment: i posted the factory

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass a callback into your test case .

```
kpi.AboutKPIController = function ($scope, Version) {

    $scope.loadVersion= function () {
      Version.getVersion().then(function(res){
                   $scope.version = res.data;
            })
    }

     $scope.loadVersion();
};
describe('dashboard: AboutKPIController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('dashboard'));
  var $controller;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter                names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
 }));
 it('testing the version number', function(done) {
    var $scope = {};
    var controller = $controller('AboutKPIController', { $scope: $scope });
    var version = 0;
    console.log($scope.version);
    $scope.loadVersion().then(function(res)){
             //can test here
             expect($scope.version).toContain("1.");
            done();
      });   
  });
```

});

Comment: ty for your answer, but when i do so, i receive `TypeError: Version.getVersion(...).then is not a function`

Comment: which one you need to know? the java service?

Answer (score 1):

I expect `Version.getVersion();` returns a promise. Your controller implemnentation should look like

```
function loadVersion() {
    Version.getVersion().then(function(version) {
        $scope.version = version;
    }); 
}
```

In your test code use `$scope.$apply` to resolve promises before you perform `except`.

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_){

    $controller = _$controller_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));
it('testing the version number', function() {
    var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var controller = $controller('AboutKPIController', { $scope: $scope });
    controller.loadVersion();
    $scope.$apply();
    expect($scope.version).toContain("1.");
});
```

Comment: when i do so, i receive `TypeError: Version.getVersion(...).then is not a function`

Comment: @messerbill You didn't show `Version.getVersion()` . I expected it to return a promise. We can give better answers if you show all the details.